# Installing Fluent Bit on Mac

Tags: fluent-bit

I want to install Fluent Bit on macOS Catalina. All the resources available are for Ubuntu and Windows.
I followed this guide for Ubuntu [1].
Can anyone guide me on this?

[1] https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/linux/debian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that you can install those debian packages on macOS. But you can surely build from the source. There is a [link on official documentation](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/sources/build-and-install) on how to build and install from source.

But from my experience you better get an understanding of possible errors that might come if you just try to download and install. [Have a look at this post about pre-requisites](https://medium.com/@anujarosha/how-to-build-fluent-bit-source-on-macos-d7424558614c). Once you have add those dependencies, surely you can build and installed on a macOS.

If you really want to ***install*** a package version on Mac, use it with [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/fluent-bit).

Answer (score 1):

You can install Fluent Bit on Mac with homebrew:

```
brew install fluent-bit
```

In my experience, on Mac it is very unstable and when I've attempted to do something simple like tailing logs you'll get lots of crashes.

Comment: What kind of crashes? What macOS were you running on?